Importing Script.sol in Foundry
Why doesn't this import need the full path?
import {Script} from "forge-std/src/Script.sol";

Something like:
import {Script} from "../lib/forge-std/src/Script.sol";

How does Foundry know the path to forge-std? Does the first way only work for the forge standard library?

In case of a library import, i.e., when importing any utility contracts available in lib folder, whether be it forge standard (i.e., forge-std) library which is available by default or be it an externally installed library (i.e., installed using forge install) like foundry-devops, chainlink, etc., it usually doesn't need the full path. And you can import like:
import {DevOpsTools} from "foundry-devops/src/DevOpsTools.sol";
import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

In some cases, you might need to map the path using remappings inside foundry.toml, like:
remappings = [
    "@chainlink/=lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts/"
]


Mapping a path is like shortening a path? Like for Chainlink, @chainlink/ can be used instead of lib/chainlink-brownie-contracts/?

Yes exactly. That's basically to retain the same import statement across different tools/environments like Hardhat, Remix, etc.
